# Getting a Signature Mismatch Error when Compiling Even though it Matches in VS.NET 2005

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction, reference

I changed a reference in my project from pointing to a specific hard-coded DLL to a project reference and now I'm getting an error telling me that the signature for some event handlers don't match even though they do.

Here's one exact message:

Method 'Private Sub ObjectsGrid_CellChange(sender As Object, e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellEventArgs)' cannot handle Event 'Public Event CellChange(sender As Object, e As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.CellEventArgs)' because they do not have the same signature.

What's also odd is if I drop the control in the GUI editor and have VS automatically create the handler, it still produces the same error.

Comment: Can you post up the rest of your compiler errors?

Comment: I switched back to the direct DLL reference for now so I don't have them handy but they were three errors all similar.

Answer (score 0):

Are the compiled dll, its respective project, and the user project all referencing the same version of the Infragistics assemblies?  From what I've seen, any time you have a signature that appears to match, an error like this means you are referencing two different versions of an assembly and attempting to use one in place of the other.